# some windows in xubuntu are too long, how to get them to shrink?

Tags: screen, display-resolution

I have netbook that has screen just 600 pixels high. Could someone tell me how to make windows and dialog boxes take up less space so they fit on screen whole? And please dont respond with the virtual higher resolution or paning the windows and dialogs, thats not a fix.

Comment: It may sound counterintuitive but it's actually how it works: Maximize the window and it will automatically fit the available screen area.

Comment: Right-click with the mouse somewhere in the top bar of the window, then in the menu shown select 'resize'. This allows you to resize the window even if the right/bottom borders are not shown.

Comment: And for dialog boxes, if they depend on the character size, lower the size of the respective (system) fonts in the settings.  Depending on your desktop system (kde, xfce, ...)  you might also change the "screen DPI" to some lower value, to get everything displayed in different (lower) size.

Comment: ridgy: the trick with screen DPI worked, thank you. now i shall find way to shrink the buttons border/margin/padding and stuff even more.